# ActiveResource::Base models seek table while testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I have an Airport model which extends ApplicationRecord and ApplicationRecord extends ActiveResource::Base

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveResource::Base
end

class Airport < ApplicationRecord
end
```

When i run tests, it gives me error like:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation
>   "airports" does not exist LINE 1: DELETE FROM "airports"
>                       ^ : DELETE FROM "airports"

Why does it look for airport table? All models extends from ActiveResource::Base and i don't have any table for models. So I can't run tests. How can i disable look up for tables in test mode? *In development mode there is no problem like that.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution. It is because

`fixtures :all`

line in test/test_helper.rb

after remove the line, it works well